# Cannot install Ubuntu 14.04 on ASUS X453M

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I was delighted when my daughter asked me to convert her laptop to Ubuntu after being very disappointed with Windows 10, so quick as a flash I built a new 14.04.3 LTS USB and tried to 'Try Ubuntu without installing'...

And it just freezes at the splash screen.

Checking a number of posts, I have updated the BIOS to the latest version and when I run the boot in verbose mode, it just hangs after the comment

*Starting system logging daemon

I've not had a problem either installing Ubuntu before (either full drive, dual boot and Ubuntu Studio) so any help would be greatly appricated so I can get my daughter back into real computing.

Comment: What is the video adapter there?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I have solved it: I used USB 2 to install and in the bios changed 'OS SELECTION to  WINDOWS 7 ( Instead of Windows 8 ) '

Works for me.

Comment: Beyond amazing! That did the very trick! My daughter is going to be delighted when she gets home to her 'new' computer!  The question I would ask - for my own information - why would the OS selection in BIOS make a difference?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. This worked for me too! (Although my use case was to boot an existing 14.04 install with a 3.13 kernel. Previously only 3.5 kernels had booted.)